# Webdav link resource

Tags: webdav, symlink

Is it possible to create Webdav resource, that would act as a symbolic link on unixes? I.e. client would understand that this resource is a link, and that it should in fact work with some other resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protocol for that is defined in [RFC 4437](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4437.html); but there aren't a lot of clients and servers supporting that.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it doesn't have wider support in clients, I could really use it now.

Comment: Actually I think the gnome client might. I haven't tested it, but it sends the Apply-To-Redirect-Ref header.

Comment: Which clients do actually support this?  Any on Windows?

Comment: The Xythos client and the MS webfolder client treat them correct on discovery, but they do not allow authoring them.

Answer (score 0):

If your symbolic link is a directory you can have a simple hack.

Instead of a symbolic link you make a normal folder that is empty (`my_empty_folder`), then on the Apache configuration you point the empty folder to the real location (`/opt/my_full_folder/`) using `Alias` and `Virtual Directory`

Something like:

```
Alias /webdav/my_empty_folder /opt/my_full_folder/
<Directory /opt/my_full_folder >
  Options +Indexes
   <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
   </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

`mod_dav` will report the folder and when you click/follow it Apache will use the content from the destination folder.

This hack will allow for webdav clients to properly see the folder and follow the contents, but also browser using apache's index